# Configuring VS Code in C on Mac for Raspberry pi Pico

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, raspberry-pi-pico

I am trying to set up VS Code on my mac, to run C code on my raspberry pi pico. I believe I have installed all of the relevant things from raspberry pi (I have a folder pico-sdk and a folder pico-examples). When I load up VS code, and navigate to pico-examples to try and build "blink.c" it gives me an underline in the line `#include "pico/stdlib.h`. I have tried a lot of troubleshooting, but have no idea why this isn't working. ChatGPT thinks I need to have some sort of "pico/stdlib.h" file in my pico-sdk folder, but that folder does not contain any such file (it has CMakeLists.txt, docs, src, CONTRIBUTING.md, external, test, LICENSE.TXT, lib, tools, README.md, pico_sdk_init.cmake, cmake, pico_sdk_version.cmake).

Another thing I am very uncertain about is this c_cpp_properties.json file that ChatGPT has gotten me to make:

Blink code:

```
/**
 * Copyright (c) 2020 Raspberry Pi (Trading) Ltd.
 *
 * SPDX-License-Identifier: BSD-3-Clause
 */

#include "pico/stdlib.h"

int main() {
#ifndef PICO_DEFAULT_LED_PIN
#warning blink example requires a board with a regular LED
#else
    const uint LED_PIN = PICO_DEFAULT_LED_PIN;
    gpio_init(LED_PIN);
    gpio_set_dir(LED_PIN, GPIO_OUT);
    while (true) {
        gpio_put(LED_PIN, 1);
        sleep_ms(250);
        gpio_put(LED_PIN, 0);
        sleep_ms(250);
    }
#endif
}
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_executable(blink
        blink.c
        )

# pull in common dependencies
target_link_libraries(blink pico_stdlib)

# create map/bin/hex file etc.
pico_add_extra_outputs(blink)

# add url via pico_set_program_url
example_auto_set_url(blink)
```

c_cpp_properties.json (made by ChatGPT)

```
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Mac",
      "includePath": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/**",
        "/Users/jfbeda/pico/pico-sdk"
      ],
      "macFrameworkPath": [
        "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks"
      ],
      "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64",
      "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc"
    }
  ],
  "version": 4
}
```

[image: A screenshot of my VS code page]

Comment: Raspberry Pi [Getting Started Guide](https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/pico/getting-started-with-pico.pdf) has whole chapter for setting up for macOS, and another chapter for setting up VSCode, yet you don't want to read but trust ChatGPT can magically help you?